# Reporting Services not shown in Browse for Servers -> Network Servers panel

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed locally and am trying to use Mangement Studio to access another 2008 R2 server in our company.  That server is running on a machine that was set up with a different network domain.

I'm able to access the database engine on the remote machine using SQL Authentication.  I understand that Analysis Services only supports Windows Authentication, so cross-domain access seems problematical, but my question is about the Reporting Services.  I try to access SSRS on the server from the 2008 R2 Management Console.  If I choose  from the Server Name dropdown, the Local Servers tab of the Browse for Servers dialog shows Analysis, Reporting, and Integration Services, in addition to Database Engines.  The Network Servers tab, however, only shows a Database Engine folder.

If, on the other hand, I select a Server Type of "Reporting Services" on the Connect to Server dialog, manually enter the server name, and supply my userid and password for Basic Authentication, I get the message: "The RPC server is unavailable", with an error code of 0x800706BA.  Our IT guys tried to fix that error by configuring

- Ports in Windows Firewall
- Remote connections
- Remote WMI requests

as per a [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365170.aspx), but the result was the same.

How do I get cross-domain access to the various services, Reporting in particular, in addition to the database engine on that server?

Answer (score 0):

Note I haven't used 2008 R2, just 2008.

If the remote server does not appear in your server list, it may not have been added to a domain.  Or perhaps it is added to a domain but the server list is not accessible to you from your domain.  If that is the case you might still be able to connect to it by name, if you add its domain to server name like this:

\domain-name\server-name

I have no way to construct a test for this in my environment.  So please let me know if you try it and it works.